# Checking my Java RSA Algorithm

Tags: java, rsa

I have to implement a RSA Algorithm for sign a document and check if anyone has changed it. Is this one correct? I can´t go to Preproduction without knowing if is ok...

```
private BigInteger n;
private BigInteger e;
private BigInteger d;
private final static SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();

private BigInteger getRandomInteger(int lengthInBits){
    return BigInteger.probablePrime(lengthInBits/2, random);
}

public RSACypher(int lengthInBits) {
    BigInteger phi;
    do {
        BigInteger p    = getRandomInteger( lengthInBits );
        BigInteger q    = getRandomInteger( lengthInBits );

        phi             = (p.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)).multiply(q.subtract(BigInteger.ONE));

        n   = p.multiply(q);
        e   = BigInteger.probablePrime(lengthInBits - 1, random);
        d   = e.modInverse(phi);
    } while ( ( n.bitCount() > (lengthInBits/2) ) || ( e.gcd( phi ).intValue() != 1 ) );
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: " I can´t go to Preproduction without knowing if is ok..." - Gold! Suppose, you write a test....

Comment: Of course I have test, and works with my own code, crypting and decrypting... But I don´t know if this is standard algoritm, for instance

Comment: You do realize that Java already has RSA cryptography built-in, right?

Comment: Yeah, I know it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Write unit tests based on RSA spec...
You can get inspiration from already written tests like [this one](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/incubator/juice/java/java5/test/OpenSSLTestRSA.java), but writing your own tests will make you more confident in the algorithm knowledge (that's my point of view ;-) )